# Caret train rf model - how long it takes to execute big data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

My data has 500000 observations and 7 variables. I split the data, 80% as training data and 20% test data. I used caret to train the model. Codes are below.I started it and it was taking so much time and eventually I had to stop it. Just wondering is there anything wrong in my model or it usually takes long time for big data? Any suggestion?

```
library(caret)
set.seed(130000000)

classifier_rf <- train(y=train$active,
                       x=train[3:5],
                       data=train,
                       method='rf',
                       trControl=trainControl(method='repeatedcv',
                                              number=10,
                                              repeats=10))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing both a train/test split and using 10-fold cross-validation? Part of the reason it's taking so long might be because you have 10 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation in your model. Try taking that part out and see how long it takes to run.

Comment: I suggest using "ranger" instead of "rf", and setting `number = 4` (or 3), `repeats = 5`, that should provide a significant speed up, and will most likely provide a better performance estimation of the model.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru: wanted to compare the results using cross validation and without cross validation.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to try parallelizing the process. For a useful resource click [here](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/pml-randomForestPerformance.md).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, `caret` still uses `RandomForest` function underneath, plus the cross validation/grid search part, so it would take a while.

For random forest model specifically, I usually just use `ranger` package, and it's so much faster. You can find their manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

`500,000` samples might be a lot for your machine depending on how powerful it is. However, you have specified repeated cross fold validation, which is a time consuming process.

When you think of single cross fold validation a model is trained K times and tested on the K-1 holdout portion. Your K is `10` in the provided context, and you are repeating it 10 times so that is 100 models.

These 100 models have to be trained and then tested, I would test your problem on a single training/testing example before moving onto cross fold validation, it will also help estimate the expected run time.

---

As an aside note, `set.seed()` does't require such a large number, any simple smaller number is usually sufficient.

You've also specified the `x`, `y`, and `data` arguments, I believe you only need to specify `data` when using a formulaic definition for the training.

Comment: I use Mac (processor: 1.86 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, memory: 2 GB 1067 MHz). I ran randomForest without cross validation and it took only couple of minutes but I wanted to see the results using caret.

Comment: It will probably take a very long time, refer to my recommendation to run a singlet case with much less data and time that.